# Not able to access nlog Folder in Bot Channel Registration

Tags: azure, bots

I created a Bot in Visual studio and published to Azure.I created Bot Channel registration also.I am able to test in web chat but since Build tab is missing under Bot Management,I am not able to access my Logs folder through online editor.I have enabled nlog to log errors in a Log folder in solution.How can i access this Log folder on server?